# React Browserrouter Url changes but page/components render only on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation, react-router

Hello I've made an app in react with a remote menu component. I've tried many many ways and my url changes but not my components rendered onto my screen. Here is the code https://github.com/DortasDimitrios/danai-delimeats please help

Comment: Hi, can you add a little bit more context to your question. Like what component is not rendered on what URL change. Also, please show your effort like debugging you have done. What part of code you think is the issue. It is not easy for community to go through your entire code and figure out the issue. It would be great if you could elaborate your problem little more.

Comment: your github link has no code :)

Comment: can you commit the package.json on the github repo

Comment: @MonicaAcha set the branch to master

Comment: so is there any errors ?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS  no no errors. Just the components do not change when i click on my Link item

Comment: @DimitrisDortas please check the answer and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initiate a new `BrowserRouter` in your menu, that will inject new history and location into the underlying components. You have to access your already created history object and change the location on it. You can do this with the `<Route>` element. Example:

```
<Route render={({history, location}) =>
    <Menu
        theme="dark"
        mode="inline"
        defaultSelectedKeys={[location.pathname]}
        onClick={this.clickAction(history)}
    >
        <Menu.Item key="/">
            <Icon type="home"/>
            <span>
                <FormattedMessage
                    id="main_layout.menu.home"
                    defaultMessage="Home"
                />
            </span>
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="/user">
            <Icon type="user"/>
            <span>
                <FormattedMessage
                    id="main_layout.menu.users"
                    defaultMessage="Users"
                />
            </span>
        </Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
}/>
[...]


private clickAction(history) {
    return (param) => {
        history.push(param.key);
    };
}
```

The render callback in `<Route>` gets the location and history object where you can now push your new location to.

Created a fixed version: https://github.com/SidiaDevelopment/danai-delimeats

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your consideration, really appreciate it! Unfortunately after editing my code and trying your recommendation, it still does not update my page. Only the url :(

Comment: did you remove the scond BrowserRouter element?

Comment: from which file and where?

Comment: https://github.com/DortasDimitrios/danai-delimeats/blob/master/src/components/Menu.js line 44

Comment: THANK YOU FROM THE DEEPEST OF MY HEART MAN! I'VE HAD NIGHTMARES FOR 5 DAYS FOR RESOLVING THIS THANKS!!!

Comment: Also I have created a fixed version: https://github.com/SidiaDevelopment/danai-delimeats. In all of your code, you should only create A SINGLE instance of `<BrowserRouter>`, there is very very special cases where you need more

Answer (score 0):

try to replace the index.js and app.js with the below code.
The issue i hope is

Make sure you wrap the main react render code in the Router. For example, with react-dom you need to wrap the app in Browser-Route

```js
// index.js

import {
  BrowserRouter
} from 'react-router-dom'
ReactDOM.render( < BrowserRouter > < App / > < /BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));


// app.js

<Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact render={props => <Homepage {...props} />} />
        <Route
          path="/about-us"
          exact
          render={props => <WhoWeAre {...props} />}
        />
</Switch>
```

Comment: thank you for your time, Unfortunately, it still does not refresh the page. only the url

Comment: is it showing a blank white page. If it is check your developer tools -> console. is there any error. Did you replace the code ?

Comment: thank you, I resolved the matter, I was just using the BrowserRouter object too many times

Comment: @DimitrisDortas sure. Happy to help please vote if it worked for you

Comment: were you able to resolve this? I'm having the same issue switching from HashRouter to BrowserRouter..